# Wait until a process is finished then start the other one

Tags: swift, asynchronous, amazon-s3, xcode9

I'm uploading user profile image on Amazon S3 and then updating my user object with the new s3 image link.

Because the process of uploading the image using the `AWSTransferManager` is async so the server update call is being executed before the s3 has finished uploading the image and sending back the link be used in the next function. How can i wait until the image is uploaded then execute the `updateUserProfile` function?

```
@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var urlString: String!
    user = tableViewVC.user


    //Upload image to Amazon S3
    urlString = self.user.uploadImageToS3(filePath: self.createImageFilePath()!, bucketName: Helper.shared.getAWSBucketName(), imageKeyName: Helper.shared.generateImageName())

        if urlString != nil && urlString != "" {
            //Then Update user profile and add image url link in main user database
            self.user.userProfilePic = urlString!
            self.user.updateUserProfile(user: self.user, token: Helper.shared.getAccessToken()!, completion: { (status, code, err, msg, body) in
                if code == 200 {
                    print(body ?? "")
                    print("Updated user profile")
                } else {
                    print(msg ?? "")
                    print(err ?? "")
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("NO URL FOUND")
        }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at `Operation` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) and `OperationQueue` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue).

Comment: @Wukerplank Thanks amazon AWSTransferManager uses asyc uploads so i changed the uploading code totally to the sync way and it worked.